# How to move UIView that contain in UIViewController when keyboard appear or dismiss?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikeyboard

I got one problem is that i wanna move my UIView(footerview) up when keyboard is showing and move it down when the keyboard is dismissed.

- my UIView (FooterView) is contain in UIViewController in Main.Storyboard that generated automatic by Xcode.
- I also have one TextField.

View Hierarchy will look like:

View:

-->TextField

--> UIView(FooterView)

**Edit**:

After I post this question I found answer by my own

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

[self.view endEditing:YES];
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
// Assign new frame to view
[self.footerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,320,65)];
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
// set it back to the original place
[self.footerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,503,320,65)];
}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: u want to move the view in up when the text filed enter

Comment: yes, i wanna move it up and down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: @vichhai Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout you can create an IBOutlet to your UIView NSLayoutAttributeBottom constraint and change it when you need. If not, you have to move your view Frame.

For example:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    self.bottomConstraintKeyboard = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.writeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:keyboardSize.height];
     [self.view removeConstraint:self.bottomConstraintZero];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.bottomConstraintKeyboard];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];    
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (self.bottomConstraintKeyboard){
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.bottomConstraintKeyboard];
        self.bottomConstraintKeyboard = nil;
    }
    [self.view addConstraint:self.bottomConstraintZero];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm not good with auto layout. So could u tell me any source to study on auto layout?

Comment: You can Google It. There are a lot of examples and tutorials. For example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1